# Storing Non-AWS API Access Tokens in Cognito User Attributes

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, authentication, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

Currently, I have configured a desktop UWP C# application which users sign into and register using AWS Cognito Users and User Pools.  The application also needs to communicate with another 3erd party API which uses a 1 time registration to return an OAuth2.0 access token and a refresh token.  The access token expires ~20mins and then refresh token last the life of the request, typically forever until revoked by the user.  I would like to store the refresh token so that it can be retrieved when the user signs in and is validated by Cognito.  Is it okay to store this access token in the Cognito user attributes when they register or do I need to store it somewhere else?  If I do need to store it elsewhere are there any AWS services which are typically used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed an AWS service for this specific purpose. Its called [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/).

Benefits;

- Default encryption in storage and transit
- You can use IAM to manage access control. So you could lock access down to one or two senior developers
- You can use IAM for fine grain access control. This means you can lock the Secret down to a specific user and its secured at the storage level
- Very simple to integrate with using the SDKs